# Use more than one PS4 Dualshock controller over bluetooth

Tags: hardware, bluetooth

I have two [Playstation 4 Dualshock controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DualShock#DualShock_4) and am thinking of getting two more. They have both bluetooth and usb connections, but prefer bluetooth to avoid cable salad — and of course to be able to conveniently play games on the big screen from the couch. Am thus far *unable to use both wirelessly at the same time*.

**How to connect and use both controllers using bluetooth at the same time?**

- Tested on macOS High Sierra (10.13) and macOS Sierra (10.12) on two separate 2015 model Macbooks.
- Can **pair** with both controllers individually, if turning bluetooth off/on between.
- Cannot **connect** with both at the same time.

As soon as one controller is connected, the other is basically ignored. As soon as the first controller is disconnected, the second one can be connected, and vice versa.

Would prefer not to use third-party (especially closed source) software, nor do I want to buy additional hardware.

Note: using Apple's Bluetooth Explorer (part of [Hardware IO Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Hardware%20IO%20Tools%20for%20Xcode), Apple Developer login required) I can reset the bluetooth stack, clear device caches, restart `blued` etcetera. This has not helped in this case, but am also not familiar enough with this advanced tool to know all the tricks.

Comment: It would be nice to either confirm (with relevant references) that connecting more than one controller using bluetooth will absolutely not work, or, of course, find a working (and reasonably convenient) solution to the problem.

Comment: Silly clarification, but do you have the Bluetooth menu enabled and can you request macOS to connect to both? You’ll want to name each differently in the Bluetooth pref pane to avoid confusion.

Comment: @bmike: Yes, I have requested connecting to both at the same time, from both the menubar bluetooth dropdown menu and the bluetooth preferences window -- doesn't work. Yes, I've tried renaming the controllers in the bluetooth preferences. It helps a bit when debugging that one controller is red and the other one black =)

Comment: Are you using Steam? What games are you trying to play? If the game(s) are available on Steam, it should work(https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248815/how-many-controllers-does-os-x-support)

Comment: @abc: yes, I'm sure it'd work using USB -- my question is about wireless bluetooth gaming from the couch. Steam/game-specific features do not matter much if the controllers won't connect to the machine/operating system first.

Comment: This seems to be a bug, as searching around the internet shows connecting multiple Dualshock controllers via Bluetooth does work.

Comment: @abc: I'd agree it's a bug of some sort. (Guessing colliding "unique id per controller".) Where do you find this works on macOS? Links? Maybe an answer?

Comment: See the Arquade link. It says "7 connections through USB, and **unlimited number of connections through pairing**". Try seeing if Steam or whatever game you are trying to play has an option for pairing controllers through the app instead of through the macOS Bluetooth menu.

Comment: @abc: I am _able to pair_ both controllers, but _not connect_ both (at the same time). Controllers in Steam's settings only show up after they have been _connected_ in macOS, so no improvement.

Comment: @JoelPurra: I am having the exact same problem as you. I am running macOS Mojave 10.14 on Macbook pro 15 inch 2017, with two PS4 Dualshock controllers, one white and one black

Comment: I have this same exact issue as well. macOS Mojave 10.14.2 with two black PS4 dual shock controllers. Called Apple Tech Support - no solution and they blame the controllers.

Comment: I'd be very curious to know if the controllers work when you connect an external Bluetooth adapter. There's been a similar-ish problem with Playstation Move controllers in recent macOS versions, and switching to an external adapter makes the problem disappear.

Comment: I've got the feeling the internal bluetooth antenna is not strong enough or something. Aside from being unable to connect two DS4 controllers at the same time, I'm also unable to connect my headphones while connected to a DS4 controller. I have to connect my headphones first and then connect my controller. When I switch to bootcamp, having both headphones and DS4 connnected at the same time is not possible at all. When I connect one device, it disconnects the other. It sounds like an external adapter might indeed be the solution.

Comment: another point of information, I can't get two dual shock controllers to work on my computer at all. One works with bluetooth, but when I plug in a USB dual shock, the bluetooth one stops working properly.

Comment: right, can't connect DualShock and DualSense at the same time on Mojave. but, also can't connect bluetooth mouse or keyboard then one of controllers connected.

Comment: If you are use bluetooth keyboard (apple like) just disconnect the keyboard (power off will be ok, not need unpair). Then try to connect both PS4 controllers - and this it. 

I check in in my old mac mini 2012 (Catalina): 
- Keyboard paired - just power off it
- Pair first controller
- Pair second controller
- both working

PS: in this case I use simple logitech mouse (no bluetooth). May be mouse should be off too

Answer (score 1):

I've so far been unable to use 2 PS4 Dualshock controllers over Bluetooth with my 2016 Macbook Pro running Mojave.

Pairing either one with my mac would make the other unable to pair. Renaming the `Wireless Controller` connection to something more decent did not help.

What **helped somewhat** was upgrading to the dreaded Catalina - I was able to pair both controllers BUT couldn't play any games with them. The games didn't consistently receive commands from either controller, I was unable to move any of the controlled characters more than a couple pixels on the screen, it was a nightmare. I assumed this was because the controllers kept interfering with one another

What **totally helped** was replacing one of the PS4 controllers with an XBOX One wireless controller. This worked & fixed all issues, we got no more interferences, and the response time was fine.

Note: all tested controllers were connected wirelessly via BT, games used were `Cuphead` and `Knights & Bikes` running on Steam.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully managed to connect up to 4 DualShock 4 v2 on my Mac mini 2012 running High Sierra 10.13.6 using an external Bluetooth Dongle (not with the builtin Mac mini BT controller).

Multiple gamepads could not be connected simultaneously as described in the question.

I purchased Mac-compatible Bluetooth USB dongles:

- Belkin F8T065bf (https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B009IQB3US)
- Sena UD100-G03 (recommended for better BT range coverage - my Mac is enclosed in a locker.

I highly recommend Sena UD100-G03 as I had issues with limited range coverage with the tiny Belkin F8T065bf. I also added an extension antenna to my Sena UD100-G03.

Both of the aforementioned dongles run on my Mac without any drivers needed: 100% plug and play!

Recommendations:

- Delete all BT devices paired from Mac
- Make sure Mac picked up the BT dongle as controller vs builtin one (ALT-click on BT icon and check for MAC address change).
- Reconnect / pair BT devices
- I had to reset one of my DualShock (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-ps4-controller-4174025)