# Cannot use two PS4 controllers on Mac M1 Big Sur

Tags: bluetooth, apple-silicon, steam

I tried this today having also followed [the advice of another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312263/use-more-than-one-ps4-dualshock-controller-over-bluetooth) on this site.

Unfortunately it did not work for me with my two PS4 controllers, named differently, and the same Belkin dongle that was recommended.

The Belkin dongle allowed me to connect two PS4 controllers (which I resetted before connecting). It would not allow my mouse or Sony headphones to connect.

*Lovers in a Dangerous Space Time*, played via Steam, recognised that two controllers were connected, but the buttons did not work on one of them, only the direction stick in the menus.

I run Big Sur 11.2.3 on a Macbook Air M1.

Maybe the solution works on a Catalina Intel Mac. I don't know.

Any help appreciated!